# > Could not create task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Could not create task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

When i build the app i got error

```
> Could not create task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not create task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.writeBaseClasses() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same error when I set the Gradle version as 8.0 milestone-5 in the Project Structure...-> Project. Changing on 7.6 version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting following error while building the project while moving up from 7.x to 8.x,

```
Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.writeBaseClasses() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.
```

I had to go through following steps as I didn't had downgrading option as in accepted answer. I was using Android Studio chipmunk which would let me select latest Gradle Version but not Android Gradle Plugin & Kotlin Gragle Plugin.

- If you are on AGP 7.2+ use `./gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true` to get prominent warning for APIs which might fail in 8.
- Upgrade Android Studio which will give you access to latest AGP & KGP. I upgraded to Eel 2022.1.1.
  If you try to upgrade kotlin gradle plugin to latest with older Android Studio you'd get,

> Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle differs from the
> one bundled into the IDE

- Set compileOptions & kotlinOptions to Java 11. Below 11 is not accepted.
- Update kotlin-gradle-plugin.
- Remove kotlin-android-extensions plugin if is in used.
- Add kotlin-parcelize plugin for accessing Parcelize class.
- Change kotlinx.android.parcel to kotlinx.parcelize.
- Remove jcenter.
- Replace deprecated onBackPressed() with

  ```
   onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
       override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
           // your code
       }
   })
  ```
- Upgrade libraries in dependencies. Retrofit library was giving an issue while building.

Finally I could build the project. Here are the versions,

[image]

*Also, these steps helped me to resolve the issue, yours might differ.*

Comment: "Update kotlin-gradle-plugin" fixed it, thanks

Comment: Why does changing the Android Gradle plugin requires us to change the Kotlin gradle plugin?

Answer (score 5):

### React Native 0.72.0 + Amplitude

I just experienced this error after adding Amplitude to a react native project.

`package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  dependencies: {
    "react-native": "^0.72.0",
    "@amplitude/analytics-react-native": "^1.3.3",
    ...
  }
}
```

To fix I added `kotlinVersion = "1.8.22"` to my root `build.gradle` file.

`<project_root>/android/build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        // required by Amplitude, overrides version included by library
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.22" // <-- add this line
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

This Solution also fixes the issue for `Could not create task ':react-native-photo-manipulator:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'`

Answer (score 2):

This might indicate a clash of a general Gradle plugin with some specific plugins that you have in your config. I has this problem when my default Gradle plugin was very modern - `8.4`

You need to investigate your root plugins (root `build.gradle`) - here you can read a version for **Kotlin compiler** and a android gradle plugin (the **AGP**):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1' // AGP
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21" // Kotlin compiler
classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.1'
classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2'
```

Next, go to your Module Settings (usually for the `:app` module) and check your Gradle plugin version:

[image]

Now, here is what a little inference should follow:

I use Kotlin 1.5.21. [It was released around mid-2021](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details), and around that time some commonly used versions of AGP were between [4.0.x to 4.2.x](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle) that would typically be [compatible with Gradle versions 6.1.1 to 6.7.1](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#expandable-1).

[image]

So for my case I had to try with version 6.1.1+, 6.5+ and 6.7.1. After trying `6.7.1` it compiled and suggested bumping version to `7.3.3`, which I did.

So the general approach towards this problem goes like this:

1. Find Kotlin version in root gradle
2. Find the corresponding AGP plugin versions that are compatible with this Kotlin release
3. Find compatible Gradle plugin version to those AGP plugin versions.

Answer (score 0):

I do Tow Changes and my project work

1st in bulid.gradle i change

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.x.x'
```

to

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.x.x'
```

from your old project, you check what your classpath version

2nd

in gradle-wrapper.properties change

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.x.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.x.x.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

AGP:7.4.2  &   Gradle:8.0 fixed my error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).