# Subject: Assistance Required with react-native-photo-manipulator APK Build Error

Tags: react-native, gradle, build, build.gradle

I hope you're doing well. I'm encountering a perplexing issue while attempting to build the APK for my React Native project that incorporates the `react-native-photo-manipulator` library. During the build process, I'm facing the following error:

```
A build operation failed.
Could not create task ':react-native-photo-manipulator:compileDebugKotlin'.
Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method AbstractKotlinCompile.execute() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.
```

Despite rigorous troubleshooting, including the addition of `kotlinVersion = "1.8.22"` to my root `build.gradle` file as suggested in relevant resources, the issue persists.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm employing:

```js
RNImageManipulator.manipulate(
  uri,
  [{ overlay, position }],
  { format: "png" }
).then(async path => {
  await RNFS.moveFile(path, newImageUri);
  await Share.open({
    url: 'file:///' + newImageUri,
    failOnCancel: false,
    title: 'Send to a specific one',
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log("error", e);
  });
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("error", e);
});
```

I've also referred to this Stack Overflow post [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025711/could-not-create-task-appcompiledebugkotlin-could-not-create-task-app)  for potential solutions, but to no avail.

Could you please offer insights into any known compatibility issues with `react-native-photo-manipulator` or suggest additional measures to address this specific error? Your guidance would be immensely valuable in resolving this issue and enhancing the robustness of my project.

Thank you for your time and assistance.