Script 'C:\flutter_windows_3.27.1-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1347
i cloned a repo from git to see if i can use its ui template , i changed the gradle wrapper to the version 8.5 because android studio gave me an error of incompatibility between the flutter version and the gradle version,so i start getting this new error now :
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * Where: Script 'C:\flutter_windows_3.27.1-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy'
> line: 1347
> 
> * What went wrong:
> > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>    > Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug'.
>       > Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
>          > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface
> org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid
> parameter to an action method.

i tried the related questions but none of them solves the problem

Possible duplicate of. :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025711/could-not-create-task-appcompiledebugkotlin-could-not-create-task-app
